# Looping best practices

Tags: c#, break, continue

I have a very large loop that loops a 1000 rows. I exit the loop if magic value 1 is found. If magic value 1 is not found but magic value 2 is found then the loop needs to skip to the beginning. Right now I am using a switch, some ifs and a goto. I have read that goto is not the best way. Is there a better way to make this work?

Comment: Please post some code. It'll help us visualize and improve it.

Comment: by "skip to the beginning", do you mean restart the loop on the next iteration, or restart the loop on the first iteration?

Comment: It would probably help if you gave some example code and what you actually want to achieve. What you describe sounds like some pretty bad coding...

Comment: Is the data in the rows constantly changing? I don't understand why you are starting from the beginning again if value 2 is found...

Comment: If you loop back to the beginning when you hit a value of 2, wont it result in an infinite loop?

Comment: @DaveK: Yes, which is why I am now terribly confused about what this guy actually wants.

Comment: This may have been discused but if part of the condition is to go back to the beigining it gives the potential to have an infinet loop problem

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To exit a loop you can use the [break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4(VS.80).aspx) statement, to go onto the next record you can use the [continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1(VS.80).aspx) statement.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    if(magicValue1)
       break;
    if(magicValue2)
       continue;
}
```

**I AM NOT CONDONING THE USE OF THE GOTO STATEMENT I AM SIMPLY POINTING OUT A POSSIBLE USE CASE**

You can use **goto** jump statement to start/exit a loop, however I would stay away from  this option unless you are using **nested looping**. I think the goto statement still has its uses for optimizing, exiting cleanly ect.. but in general it is best to use it **quite** sparingly.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{ 
  start:

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
     if(magicValue1)
       goto end;
    if(magicValue2)
       goto start;
  }
}
end :
```

Comment: -1, goto may have its uses but this isn't one them. In all cases like this you can refactor the nested loops into a separate method and use return.

Comment: Points 1 and 2 are not right. For 1 you could just wrap it in a try {} finally {} block and it would look much better and see my other comment for number 2.

Comment: +1 For being able to have the ability to explain a concept without advocating its usage in all cases.

Comment: @Samuel - goto is not the big bad scary monster that everyone makes out. It is super fast and CAN BE very readable when used correctly. I do not advocate its use and have only used it once in my entire programming career.

Comment: @Samuel - I think it is good to have a grasp of all the elements of a language and use them when needed rather then just saying "Its bad don't use it"

Comment: Never said they are monsters and while they do have uses, nested loops isn't a good one. And gotos can be reable, but refactoring and sticking to SRP will produce vastly more readable code.

Comment: @Samuel refactoring can be good thing, but it is not always an option. Saying they should not be used in a nested for statement is the wrong way to approach things. Each situation should be evaluated on its own merit.

Comment: In this particular case, there is nothing evil about `goto` - it is not fundamentally different to `break` and `continue` (the latter just happen to use an implicit label). If you oppose the use of `goto` in such cases, you should oppose `break` and `continue` as well.

Answer (score 10):

How about this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    if(values[i] == MAGIC_VALUE_1) {
        break;
    } else if(values[i] == MAGIC_VALUE_2) {
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

If by "skip to the beginning" you mean "skip this record and process the next one," replace `i = 0` with `continue`.

Comment: was just doing that with a While loop instead

Comment: The only problem with this (and it will probably be a problem with the original author's wording of the problem), is that once you hit magic value 2, it will start all over until it hits magic value 2, then it will start all over, infinitely. Your code is definitely right, based on what he is saying

Comment: I'd actually recommend using a while loop for this, as most people expect the 3rd statement in the for loop to be the only thing that modifies the index variable.  A while loop would not induce that preconception and thus be easier to grok.

Comment: @TheTXI: Perhaps he's modifying the data, so on the next run the values are different. According to the question this answer is a valid one.

Comment: @TheTXI: I think the OP must be modifying the values in the loop. Otherwise, this obviously results in an infinite loop, as you and DaveK have pointed out.

Comment: @rmeardor: +1 for the recommendation, -1 for the use of "grok" =))

Comment: @Pawel: I was not trying to harp on CBG at all, I upvoted him. I was just trying to add a note that based on the limited amount the OP described, it's going to hit an infinite loop. I can't fault CBG for writing the correct solution to a WTF problem.

Comment: @TheTXI: WTF should be a tag. =)

Comment: Steve McConnell would be sad - You're making changes to the loop counter in the loop...

Comment: -1: Changing the loop counter in the middle of the loop body is really bad practice; while it's permitted by the language, it violates the principle of least surprise and is a maintenance booby trap.

Answer (score 3):

A `while` variation with no `break`:

```
bool continue = true; int i = 0;
while (i < 1000 && continue){
    if(values[i] == MAGIC_VALUE_1) {
        continue=false;
    } else if(values[i] == MAGIC_VALUE_2) {
        i = 0;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment yet ( 1 rep point away)

but wouldn't this be better:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    if (magicValue1)
    {
       break;
    }
    else if (magicValue2)
    {
       dosomething();
       i=0;
    }
}
```

and I'm not sure by whats meant by "restart the search".

Comment: The original post is tagged C#, so you'd want "else" instead of "Else". And your if statements need to compare the magicValues *to* something, like:  if(values[i]==magicValue1)

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking #2 case to mean that you want to not perform (i.e. skip) the loop body in the #2 case and not that you want to reset the loop to 0. (See the code comments if I've got that backward.)

This suggestion may be controversial because of the less conventional condition in the for loop could be said to be low on the self-documenting scale, but if that doesn't bother you, a concise way of writing what I think you you want is:

```
        for (int i= 0; i<values.Length && values[i]!= MAGIC_1; i++)
        {
            if (values[i] == MAGIC_2)
            {
                // Don't do the loop body for this case but continue on looping
                continue;
                // If you want to reset the loop to zero instead of skip the 2 case,
                // comment-out the continue; and un-comment the line below:
                // i=0;
            }
            // Do long loop body here
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just note that if you set the counter back to 0 if MagicValue is 2, and your code never changes the values, you are probably going to be in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

A more complex could be:

We define 2 Extension Methods.

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static bool isMagic_1(this int i)
   {
         return i == 1;
   }

   public static bool isMagic_2(this int i)
   {
         return i == 2;
   }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  {
     if(i.isMagic_1())
       break;
     if(i.isMagic_2())
       continue;
  }
```

hope this helps!

Comment: wouldn't it be better to return true or false

Comment: in fact is returning true or false.